# Hibernate problem - “Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class”

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entities, LCPUserDetails and LCPUserPrivilege. LCPUserDetails has a List class member, so a One to Many relationship. When I run my unit test I am getting this exception:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LCP_USER_DETAILS")
public class LCPUserDetails {
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
 mappedBy = "userDetails")
    private List<LCPUserPrivilege> privileges= new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LCP_USER_PRIVILEGE")
public class LCPUserPrivilege {
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private LCPUserDetails userDetails;
}
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add LCPUserPrivilege to the classes of your persistence.xml file.

Comment: @JBNizet we are not using any such files

Comment: Then find how/where the entities are listed or discovered.

Answer (score 0):

As Sheik Sena Reddy mentioned, you have to update your list of entities. If you don't use an xml file, you can check where you set your EntityManagerFactory and add a list of package that your EMF will scan to list your entities `emf.setPackagesToScan(['my.package.to.scan']);`.